# Load balance background tasks in Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-webjobs

I am developing an ASP.NET application that will be hosted as an Azure web app.  Part of the app will continuously record multiple web-based cameras by retrieving a snapshot every N seconds.  I would like to design the app so that the processes that record the cameras can be run on multiple instances.  I would like it to load balance between all instances, but not duplicate effort for any one camera.

For example, if I have 100 cameras, and am running on 2 instances, I want each instance to get 50 cameras to process.  If I have 5 instances, each instance should get 20 cameras to process. As I add cameras or scale instances up/down I would like for the system to load balance the work evenly.

If it's feasible, I would rather not spin up dedicated VMs just for processing cameras, due to increased cost.

I'm somewhat familiar with Akka.NET, Hangfire, and WebJobs, but am unclear if these will help in this scenario. I have used Hangfire and WebJobs to do background processing, but not with this sort of load-balancing requirement.  Will these or some other framework or tool help me load balance these background tasks evenly across Azure Web App Instances? How should I go about setting up these or another framework to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't think you want to try to "balance" the servers. I think you just want to make sure the work is well distributed. If I were you, I would use a queue system like SQS to queue up all of the cameras that need a snapshot and let each instance worker dequeue one at a time and process it.

A good approach could be to have a master server responsible for queueing up the snapshots, and then have all of your workers servers simply work out of this shared queue. Even if one server happens to process more than the others, that is fine since the others were working out of the same queue. It just means that this server was able to process its jobs more quickly than the others.

To be honest, there are a lot of ways to approach this. You could do something as simple as just having a shared list of your cameras, with a timestamp for the last snapshot, and use this to work off of. Each server would request a camera, they would look at the list and find one that was stale, and then update the timestamp and perform the snapshot for the camera. The downside to something like this is you are going to struggle with non-atomic operations and the possibility of multiple workers making the request at the same time and both working on the same server. These are the type of things that a queue system will help you with, because as soon as one of those queue items are in flight, they will no longer be available. And also, because each server is responsible for invalidating their items once they are finished, if a server were to crash mid-snapshot, this work would simple go back into the queue.

No matter which solution you choose, it is going to boil down to having a central system/list for serving up stale cameras.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure WebJob SDK uses the Storage Account you set up to balance the work between the various instances that are running your Jobs. You can gain finer control by using a Queue to divide up the work that needs doing and then scale your App Service Plan based on the Queue length.

Here's a rough picture of that architecture:[image]

Comment: This is close to what I want, but I don't understand when to populate the queue.  If I do it in the web app start up, then how do I ensure only one web app instance populates the queue so that I can avoid, say, 3 instances queueing a job for the same camera?

Comment: You drop something in the Queue for every image you need to process. A Client only uploads an image to one App at any given time, thus you shouldn't necessarily have duplicates. If you're sensitive to duplicates, generate a unique identifier on the client side (sessionid-streamname-timestamp) and when you process the image, save it with that id. Thus, you can prevent accidental duplicates.

Comment: This isn't to process user uploads of images, though. This is a continuous process to record web-based cameras.  For example, I have a CamRecorderJob that will continuously grab a frame every N seconds.  When the app starts, I need it to spin up one CamRecorderJob for each camera in a list.  If I put the logic to start those jobs in "App_Start"/Global.asax/etc., then it will run once on every instance.

Comment: Hmm, then you could just use a WebHook Trigger from the extensions library - https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions. Then you're just using an HTTP call to start up the Job. Though, I'd caution you that what you're doing sounds like it might have some reliability issues. What happens if the WebJob crashes/restarts?

Comment: What would trigger the webhook call? Scheduler?  I'm not dead-set on WebJobs.  In the end, I just want a way to spread CameraRecorderJobs efficiently across available compute.  If one crashes, I want it to restart.

Comment: Actually, TimerTrigger looks like what I need: "The TimerTrigger also handles multi-instance scale out automatically - only a single instance of a particular timer function will be running across all instances (you don't want multiple instances to process the same timer event)."